# Why is this ideal generated by a regular sequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

This is a question regarding Exercise 18 in http://www.math.utah.edu/agtrtg/commutative-algebra/Boocher_lectures.pdf

Let $I$ be the ideal of the polynomial ring $k[a,b,c,d,e,f]$

> $I=(a^2+b^2+ab+cd+ef,b^3-6abc+def,c^2e^2+f^4)$.

Krull's altitude theorem gives $\mathrm{ht}\;I\leq 3$. There is a term order such that the height of the initial ideal is 3. Why does this imply that $I$ is generated by a regular sequence?

Comment: I don't know how to conclude that $I$ is generated by a regular sequence from the previous claims, but this is a general result that holds for ideals where the grade equals the number of generators.

Comment: @user26857: how do you prove that the grade of this ideal is 3?

Comment: The height of $I$ and $in I$ are equal. In a Cohen-Macaulay ring, if height $I$ = the number of generators of $I$, then the generators form a regular sequence.

Comment: @Youngsu In a Cohen-Macaulay *local* ring, if height $I$ = the *minimal* number of generators of $I$, then the generators form a regular sequence.

Comment: @AlexM Your ring is Cohen-Macaulay, and this entails that grade I = height I.

Comment: @Youngsu do you have a reference for the equality $\mathrm{ht}\;I=\mathrm{ht}\;\mathrm{in}_<I$?

Comment: It follows from Theorem 2.18 in the cited reference.